# three.js - Buffer Geometry with aoMap and second uv coordinates

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working with a SEA3D model, loaded as `BufferGeometry`, and adding externally an `aoMap`.

However there is some problem with both maps.

- The `aoMap` just does not affect the color of the model.

In three.js documentation, there is the a reference

> The aoMap requires a second set of UVs.

In `BufferGeometry`, I know the UV info is on the `geometry.attributes.uv`.

How do I get the second set of UV's so I can get the `aoMap`?

Thank you

Comment: You can add a 2nd set of UVs to a `BufferGeometry` like so: `var uvs = geometry.attributes.uv.array; geometry.addAttribute( 'uv2', new THREE.BufferAttribute( uvs, 2 ) );` Try it and repost your question.

Comment: Thank you @WestLangley. I add it but I still get no result from activating the aoMap. The lightMap seems to work though.
Any idea why
I can see this is not related to displacementMap also..
I can add a link to the dev version..

Comment: Got it working, got it working, I needed to update the cache.. Thank you very much @WestLangley I changed the question so if you want to add your anwser I will vote as correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a 2nd set of UVs to a `BufferGeometry` like so:

```
var uvs = geometry.attributes.uv.array;
geometry.addAttribute( 'uv2', new THREE.BufferAttribute( uvs, 2 ) );
```

(Of course, using this pattern, the 2nd set will match the first set.)

three.js r.74

Answer (score 3):

I am currently using r89, and it's seems that the code above doesn't work any more. I have visited three.js documentation page and found that you don't need to copy array and then create new instance of BufferAttribute object, you can just use copy method of the BufferAttribute object.

This have worked for me

```
geometry.attributes.uv2 = geometry.attributes.uv.clone()
```

As in the previous answer you will end up with two identical sets of UVs.

Comment: The accepted answer works for me. In your answer, it is sufficient to simply do this: `geometry.attributes.uv2 = geometry.attributes.uv;`.

Answer (score 0):

there
also in the following way you can assign the textures to UV2

```js
//                map|aoMap|normalMap|metalnessMap|roughnessMap|alphaMap etc...
object3d.material.map.channel = 2;
object3d.material.needsUpdate = true;
```

Regards